# Changing the position of graphs that are stacked, using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, facet-wrap

I am trying to plot 4 graphs on top of each other using ggplot's function facet_wrap. The plot positioning goes from top to bottom in this order: Central, Eastern, Northern, Western. However, I would like the order to be: Eastern, Central, Northern, Western. My code looks like this...

```
region_plot = ggplot(region_data, aes(fill = Disease, x = Year, y = region_data$Average_rate)) +
  ylab("Average Rate") +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Lyme Disease - Confirmed" = "red", "Lyme Disease - Probable" = "grey")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  ylim(0, 260) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Zone)) +
 facet_grid(Zone ~ ., scales = "free_y") 
region_plot
```

Is there a way to change the order of plots when stacking plots?

Comment: Whenever I see a question with `ggplot2` and *"order of facets/labels/..."*, invariably the answer has to do with `factor`s. I can't show you anything with your data, but create a `factor` and facet on that.

Comment: I agree with @r2evans .  Check this tutorial, it might be useful for your purpose.  https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot-revisited/

Comment: That helps, didn't know the right terminology so I was finding it difficult to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your `Zone` into a `factor`.

Some fake data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(dir=sample(c("North", "East", "West", "South"), size=100, replace=TRUE), x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
```

The plots:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(dir ~ .) + labs(title="Order: alphabetic")

dat$dirfctr <- factor(dat$dir, levels=c("North", "South", "East", "West"))
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(dirfctr ~ .) + labs(title="Order: factor")
```

[image: side-by-side ggplots, alpha and factor order]

Two notes:

- I generated a second variable and used that; other SO answers (or off-site tutorials) might just replace the original variable with the `factor` ... but I like keeping the original as a `character` because during dev, I often play around with various things that deal with the two separately (but it is just a preference); and
- I tend to prefer generating the `levels=` parameter programmatically if there is any chance that some other level will pop up in the data; otherwise, you'll find `NA`s in your factors. An alternative might be that you always want something first and the others don't matter, in which case `levels=c("North", setdiff(c("North"), unique(dat$dir)))` is a way. There are several utilities/functions/packages that can help with managing your factors/levels.